# software to create timed music 3m 1m 3m

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, mp3, music, compact-disc

I am looking for a program that will allow me to create a sort of training CD.

Something that will let me take a bunch of songs and let me limit them to 3 minutes (maybe more or maybe less) and have one song repeat for 1 minute.

So the CD would be like

3m 1m 3m...etc

Anyone know a program that will allow me to do this?

Using Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For freedom and control, just use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

You can cut and paste as you choose to limit the length of your existing songs, or loop them, and then just burn the resulting tracks with iTunes or whatever.

Comment: Even better, Audacity is available for multiple OS's, not just Windows.

Answer (score 1):

try [Acoustica Mixcraft](http://www.acoustica.com/mixcraft/), it should satisfy your need

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there no freeware software that would do the same?